# USB Devices doesn't work but show up in lsub and dmesg

Tags: debian, usb, keyboard, mouse

I found this article and seem to have a similar Problem.
[Why is USB not working in Linux when it works in UEFI/BIOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72625/why-is-usb-not-working-in-linux-when-it-works-in-uefi-bios?newreg=bb783ab153a94ea08ff71c71dc28861c)

MyConfig
Fujitsu Board Qxx Chipset
i5-2400

I use VPro KVM and the input doesn't work in debian jessie.
Live CD and rescue mode are fine.

I tried an upgrade to Kernel 4.5.

To get network back to work I used `service restart network-manager` in rescue mode.

Normal usb devices work again after replugging them.

I changed mainboard and CPU recently, but I had similar problems with the last system.
I don't have a Gigabyte board. And tried nearly all settings in bios.

Following the `lsusb` output. `001:004` must be the vPro KVM.

`lsusb` :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c529 Logitech, Inc. Logitech Keyboard + Mice
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

just the `dmesg | grep '2-3'`. The vPro KVM device.

```
[    4.284230] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    4.491046] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=002b
[    4.491051] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    4.491061] usb 2-3: Product: USBr Composite Device
[    4.491063] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Intel
[    4.491065] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 0001
[    5.921587] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

Why is it disconnecting?? In rescue mode it reconnects automatically.
I can even launch lightdm from rescue mode and then use it with keyboard and mouse.

[image: dmesg rescue mode]

Other "real" USB devices have the same problem.
The vPro device must be a virtual USB.

Comment: Did you try using [Solaar](http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/) to pair your devices? It might not be the case, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @GAD3R - _again, please stop_ adding the actual text you are editing into the _edit summary_; the edit summary should be something like "formatting, removing thanks, fixed missing stuff" etc

Comment: @Tico: thanks! but I don't have problems with the logitech receiver. It isn't a unifying receiver at all. Standard old 2,4Ghz. Replugging it and it is working fine. Even after a restart!

Comment: @daftmab Plugging it back to front USB and same Problem again. dmesg connect -> disconnect. Problem persists on USB Hub `2-x`! (Perhaps?) Logitech Receiver `2-1.3` / vPro KVM `2-3`. But not in secure mode or live CD!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `/etc/rc.local` was wired.
I deleted it.
And now everything seems fine.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
su user -c '/home/user/scripte/synergyc.sh' &
exit 0
```

This is my current script.
But the broken one looked exactly the same.
How do I mark the question as solved?

Comment: You'll have to wait a couple of days before you can mark your own answer as the correct one.