# Trying read a Sata USB 3.0 Kali linux light

Tags: usb, kali-linux, external-hdd

I'm try read my USB 3.0 HDD in my Kali Linux.

uname -a:

```
Linux kali 4.8.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.11-1kali1 (2016-12-08) x86_64 GNU
```

When I've used "gparted recovery" the other linux is be able to read the hdd

I've see this post: [Why is USB not working in Linux when it works in UEFI/BIOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72625/why-is-usb-not-working-in-linux-when-it-works-in-uefi-bios) but it doesn't work for me.

I have an Asus hero vII.

if I put in my board xhci handoffs enable, then the  usb 3.0 ports can't read the hdd, However can read a usb device

I'm using `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` in the grub

dmesg:

```
[   74.359222] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   74.379818] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3320
[   74.379822] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[   74.379824] usb 4-1: Product: Expansion Desk
[   74.379825] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[   74.379827] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: NA4K2J9H
[   74.439738] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   74.448438] scsi host8: uas
[   74.448497] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   74.449853] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion Desk   0711 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   74.495336] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   74.495458] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[   75.523126] ........ready
[   82.692033] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[  113.644998] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  113.645004] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 3f 00 04 00
[  113.645099] scsi host8: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[  118.752785] usb 4-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[  123.872488] usb 4-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[  129.504188] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  134.879916] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  135.103919] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  135.164152] scsi host8: uas_post_reset: alloc streams error -19 after reset
[  135.164175] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  242.650508] INFO: task systemd-udevd:1678 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  242.650510]       Tainted: P           O    4.8.0-kali2-amd64 #1
[  242.650511] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  242.650511] systemd-udevd   D ffff8ad85ec58180     0  1678    366 0x00000100
[  242.650514]  ffff8ad852353140 ffff8ad855231000 00000000fffffffa ffff8ad8298dbcd0
[  242.650515]  ffff8ad8298dc000 0000000000000000 ffff8ad850688bc0 ffff8ad8298dbea8
[  242.650516]  ffffffffc09e6500 ffff8ad8531a4500 ffffffff9b1dd6d1 ffffffffffffffff
[  242.650517] Call Trace:
[  242.650524]  [<ffffffff9b1dd6d1>] ? schedule+0x31/0x80
[  242.650527]  [<ffffffff9ac9c2d9>] ? async_synchronize_cookie_domain+0x69/0x140
[  242.650528]  [<ffffffff9acbba00>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
[  242.650530]  [<ffffffff9ad78550>] ? do_init_module+0xbc/0x1ed
[  242.650533]  [<ffffffff9ad01942>] ? load_module+0x23b2/0x2a60
[  242.650534]  [<ffffffff9acfe2f0>] ? __symbol_put+0x60/0x60
[  242.650536]  [<ffffffff9ad02236>] ? SYSC_finit_module+0xc6/0xf0
[  242.650539]  [<ffffffff9ac03b8a>] ? do_syscall_64+0x7a/0xd0
```

I can't see my hdd.

When I've connected a internal sata must reboot pc because it cant read hdd.

**`lsusb -vv | grep -i Seagate -A9`** (In port USB 2.0) because in 3.0 not work

```
root@kali:~# lsusb -vv | grep -i Seagate -A9 
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 0bc2:3320 Seagate RSS LLC SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bc2 Seagate RSS LLC
  idProduct          0x3320 SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 Seagate
  iProduct                3 Expansion Desk
  iSerial                 1 NA4K2J9H
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           85
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
```

lsusb and lsusb -vv

```
root@kali:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@kali:~# lsusb -vv

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc534 Unifying Receiver
  bcdDevice           29.00
  iManufacturer           1 Logitech
  iProduct                2 USB Receiver
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 RQR29.00_B0015
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      59
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     177
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0014  1x 20 bytes
        bInterval               2
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
  idProduct          0x8001 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              11
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             8
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        0 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0100 power
   Port 7: 0000.0100 power
   Port 8: 0000.0103 power enable connect
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            4.08
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.8.0-kali2-amd64 ehci_hcd
  iProduct                2 EHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x02
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
  idProduct          0x8009 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0001  1x 1 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             6
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        0 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            4.08
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.8.0-kali2-amd64 ehci_hcd
  iProduct                2 EHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1a.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x02
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: can you show `lsusb`  with the USB 3.0 HDD plugged. Edit you question please for that.

Comment: stupid aliases I mean post `lsusb -vv`  | grep -i Seagate -A9 | egrep -i 'vendor|product`

Comment: @Bahamut Ty dude, I've edited the post with the lsusb and lsusb -vv

Answer (score 0):

`touch /etc/modprobe.d/uas-ignore.conf`

`echo "options usb-storage quirks=0x0bc2:0x3320:u" | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/uas-ignore.conf`

This "tell" the Modul uas to ignore this HD. [uas](http://linux-sunxi.org/USB/UAS#UAS_capable_Allwinner_SoCs) Reboot.